# Android X migration cheat sheet

Tags: android, androidx, material-components-android, material-components

XML tags are not migrating with android studio .. the ones that are, are not linking properly. XML tags after running migration are completely useless.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, is your question/answer any different than this : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings ?

Comment: nope this is different .. these are xml tags to be used in your project

Comment: I think this would get lost in StackOverflow and end up not being of any use to anybody. Maybe it would be better as a blog post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have compiled this cheat sheet for my app, thought it would be useful for others as well so here you go.

```
android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialog
com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialog 

android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout 

android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

androidx.core.view.ViewPager
androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager

android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior
com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior 

android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar 

android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView
com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView

android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView
com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView 

androidx.appcompat.widget.CardView
androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 

android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

androidx.core.view.ViewPager
androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager

importandroidx.core.widget.DrawerLayout
androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 

androidx.appcompat.widget.RecyclerView
androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView 

androidx.core.view.PagerAdapter
androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter

importandroidx.core.app.FragmentManager
importandroidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager

android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout

android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout

android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout

android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView

android.support.v4.widget.Space
androidx.legacy.widget.Space
```

Comment: `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` -> `com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar`  
`androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`  -> `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the Android > AndroidX converter native to Android Studio, but I can imagine it having it's flaws.

It sounds like you are looking for manual assistance. You can not only see a near-complete reference list [here](https://gist.github.com/alexjlockwood/c59e74e95037f6c230dde8a39c328970). There is even a script made to rename *just* these elements down at the bottom.

Furthermore, you can find multiple resources online such as this [here](https://androidx.de/androidx/annotation/package-summary.html), which really explains the different params and uses for lots of the new androidx libs.

This is of course assuming that [Google's official AOSP dev help site](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/packages) was not helpful. ;)